# How do I pass a post ID to the page URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, methods, get

I am trying to pass / append the POST ID of an AUTHORS POST to the end of a PAGE URL.

My effort so far to generate a link is as follows

```
<?php foreach(get_posts(array('author' => $author_id)) as $post)?>
<a href="http://example.com/dashboard/form_page?gform_post_id=<?php echo $post->ID ?>">Link</a>
```

But this seems to get first POST ID made on the site. Not the ID of the Authors POST. Note: It is a custom post id I am trying to get from the Author.

The Page URL is this: 
http://example.com/dashboard/form_page

What I am looking for is this: 
http://example.com/dashboard/form_page?gform_post_id=476

Where the POST ID is the ID of the POST Created by the Author logged in. (In my system only 1 post per Author)

Cheers in advance...

Plugin used: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-update-post/

Comment: Could you put the `gform_post_id` part in the `action` of the `form`? (Something like `<form action="http://example.com/dashboard/form_page?gform_post_id=<?php echo intval($_POST['gform_post_id']); ?>" method="post">` for example.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I not sure how to try this but I will give a look at the code of the form. However is your code suggestion getting the POST ID of the page the form is on? I need to get the POST ID of a Post the user is Author to and not the post id of the page the form is on if that makes sense?

Comment: I do not know the plugin, so I do not know the actual variables. Perhaps it is something like `$post->id`, rather than `$_POST['gform_post_id']`, but you get the idea. Good luck!

Comment: Hi ACJ, cheers man..I will give it a go with what you wrote and see if it works...

Comment: hi ACJ, I made a change to the original post to make things clearer...Does that maybe help you in anyway point out what I might be able to do?

Comment: It now seems to me the `foreach` is broken by closing PHP, and the `a href` is parsed only once with the array/object that is returned by `get_posts()`. However, if every author has one post, as you implied, this should not be a problem. Try `print_r(get_posts(array('author' => $author_id)));` to see if it returns the values you would expect. Also,  I would use `$post = get_posts(array('author' => $author_id))` instead of the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php foreach(get_posts(array('author' => $author_id)) as $post) { ?>
    <a href="http://example.com/dashboard/form_page?gform_post_id=<?php echo $post->ID 
    ?>">Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```